# Uploading images through dashboard page

Tags: concrete5

I have add some dashboard pages to my conrete5 install.  One of pages has a form that needs allows the user to upload an image.  Are there any libraries for uploaded images of shall I do it in native PHP?  I found [this](http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/files/importers/) in the documentation but I don't think its what I want.

I thought I'd ask before I started and to see if anyone else has done anything like this before

Comment: From your question, I think the FileImporter is exactly what you want. Why don't you think so? What's wrong with it insofar as your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making use of the built-in Asset Library helper.  This will add a field to your form that allows the user to access all of the images in your site's File Manager, and upload a new image if necessary.  [Here's](http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/files/using-in-blocks-interfaces) the relevant page in the concrete5 documentation.

Let's say you wanted to add a field to your form called "photo".  Here's an example of what you would add to the part of your dashboard page's view where the form is rendered:

```
$al = Loader::helper(‘concrete/asset_library’);
$al->image('photo', 'photo', 'Select a photo', $photo);
```

In this case, `$photo` is used to represent the currently-selected image, if known.